# Chrome extension wait until ajax call to be finished

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having issues with trying to withhold the script from searching through the page until the ajax call is completed for a page in which I trigger a onClick event.

What I'm trying to achieve with my extension is to check my chatrooms every two seconds for new message, and if there are any, open up that chatroom to retrieve new messages and send it to my server for automated ordering process. Unfortunately, I have the authority to fiddle with the web page or its scripts. Also, the scrips for this page is written as private, so I cannot really access the functions inside the script.

So here's what I've been thinking that I should do:

1. check for any new messages every two seconds
2. if there are any, then open up the chatroom and WAIT til messages are loaded.
3. retrieve new unread messages of that chatroom and continue onto the next one with new message if there exists one.

Here's my excerpt of code:

```
    $.each(chatRoomArr, function(index) {

    $("#"+unreadChatRooms[index]).trigger("click");
        setTimeout(function() {
            tmp = $("#chatLogs > div.line > p.hr_talk > span:last").parent().parent()
                .nextAll("div.conv.usr").children("span.comment").children("span.txt_cont");
            console.log("tmp[index].innerText = " + tmp[index].innerText);
            tmpArr = [];
            $.each(tmp, function(idx) {
                tmpArr.push(tmp[idx].innerText);
            });
            message[unreadChatRooms[index][1]] = tmpArr;
        }, 278);
    });
```

The problem here is that I'm just guessing that it takes a little bit longer than 277ms to load and render the messages, because from js console I could verify that at 277ms, it fails to retrieve data from the page. And I cannot just rely on this magic number that I got from test-and-trial because I am very sure that this value WILL vary due to various reasons (my internet connection, etc.)

So, I was wondering if there is a way to really mark down that specific ajax call from the triggered click event being completed?

Comment: you probably need a interceptor.

Comment: @Umer Hayyat I'm just very new to developing so bare with me. I've looked up what interceptors are. From what I can understand, I need direct access to the specific function that I would like to put interceptors on don't I? As I've mentioned, I have no direct access to the specific function that executes the ajax call in my case. Or am I not understanding it right?